Dymola's translateModel function with a model name and modifiers for the problem argument
Why does Dymola report that the variable x0 is undeclared when calling translateModel(problem="Sandbox.Test(x_start=x0)")?  Notice that translateModel is a built-in, internal, Dymola function to initiate a model translation from the command line.  The input to the function is the class as a string input.
In my example to demonstrate my question, the model Test is defined as in the following:
model Test
  parameter Real x0=1.234;
  parameter Real x_start=-1.234;
  Real x(start=x_start, fixed=true);

equation 
  der(x) = time;

end Test;

As expected, I can extend from test and apply the same modifier as in the following model:
model Tester
  extends Test(x_start=x0);
end Tester;

In the case of the Tester model, the call to translateModel(problem="Sandbox.Tester") succeeds without error.
This seems similar to the question posed in this post, but it's not quite the same.
So can someone clarify why the call translateModel(problem="Sandbox.Test(x_start=x0)") fails?
Do the modifiers in this string need to be literal values? Or is there a different way to make this call with the modifer?

I have tested the code for Test and Tester in OpenModelica and works as you say, i.e. in Tester the code line "extends Test(x_start=x0)" here x0 do refer to the declaration of x0 inside Test. If you have another declaration of x0, say before the the code line "extends Test(...)" then you get compilation error. It would be helpful if you add code for a simple version of "translateModel()" so at least I better understand it all.

The translateModel function is a Dymola function to execute a model translation from the command line (Dymola command line).  I should have clarified that in my original post.  I'll edit it to make that clear.

The modifiers in that argument for translateModel are handled similarly to
model Tester=Test(x_start=x0);

instead of as
model Tester
  extends Test(x_start=x0);
end Tester;

So, even if not strictly limited to literals you cannot use any local variables from the model in the modifier.
However, I'm unsure why you need this - if you included a more realistic example it might be easier to suggest another solution.

Perfect, thanks Hans, this answers my question. I hadn't thought about it from the point of view of the short class definition, nor that translateModel handles modifiers in a similar way. The specific case came up as part of some internal testing infrastructure, where a string similar to this example was causing a translation failure for a specific test case. I couldn't explain why it would fail and so sought the answer here.

@JesseGohl if this answers your question, please consider "Accepting" it as well.
